# How do I send a Hello, world! message to an ETH address through DATA? That is would be visible on Etherscan

Tags: blockchain

How do I send a "Hello, world!" message to an ETH address through DATA? That is would be visible on Etherscan
That's the whole question

Is that possible in any way?

Answer (score 3):

you can use `eth.sendTransaction` method to send the message along with the ether.

```
eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0],to:eth.accounts[1],value:web3.toWei(1‌00,'Wei'),data:web3.toHex('Hello World!')})
```

In the mist wallet under send tab select the more option to add the message along with the ether transactions. In data, section add the text in hexadecimal format.